# PHP $_GET Help to create a link

Tags: php

Iam try to create a simple page to get IP and Port with $GET

Example index.php?ip=193.192.58.12&port=27016

I get server error with my code

```
if (isset($_GET['ip']) && $_GET["port"]) {

$ip = $_GET["ip"];  
$queryport = $_GET["port"]; 


$ip = '';
$queryport = ;

$socket = @fsockopen("udp://".$ip, $queryport , $errno, $errstr, 1);

stream_set_timeout($socket, 1);
stream_set_blocking($socket, TRUE);
fwrite($socket, "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\x54Source Engine Query\x00");
$response = fread($socket, 4096);
@fclose($socket);

$packet = explode("\x00", substr($response, 6), 5);
$server = array();

$server['name'] = $packet[0];
$inner = $packet[4];
$server['players'] = ord(substr($inner, 2, 1));
$server['playersmax'] = ord(substr($inner, 3, 1));

var_dump (json_encode( $server ));

    } else {

  echo "Serveri nuk ekziston";
}
```

Comment: Describe more about the error

Comment: Why `$queryport = ;` after setting it to the `$_GET` value?

Comment: Stop using `@` and write some error handling for them instead.

Comment: You overwrite both `$ip` and `$queryport`

Comment: Actually @user2959229 is right. Why do you assign an empty string to `$ip` and then left `$queryport` in that situation

Comment: first of all... you can't set `blocking` in `udp` protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is causing a problem by overwriting/removing the values that you've just grabbed from `$_GET`:

```
$ip = $_GET["ip"];  
$queryport = $_GET["port"]; 

$ip = '';
$queryport = ;       //    <<-- syntax error
```

Remove `$ip = '';` and `$queryport = ;` and test again.

Also remove the `@` from `@fsockopen` so you can see when it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data['status'] = 1;
// Explode extra flags from packet part //
$extras = explode("\x00", substr($packet[4], 25)); error?
$extras = explode(",", $extras[0]);//
$data['flags'] = "";
foreach($extras as $flag)
```

Comment: Please provide more details. Your answer doesn't look finished (`foreach` loop is empty), so please review it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please put at least one explanatory line on top of your Cod.e and ensure its either your intellectual work or is cited properly